# Tips for avoiding Stackoverflow in recursion

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I am writing an algorithm for a ASP.NET/C# website that plans a schedule for students, teachers and class rooms. I do this by doing recursion like this (pseudo code):

```
public Booking GetBooking(..., ref numberOfTries) {
     numberOfTries--;
     if (numberOfTries == 0) {
          return null;
     }

     if (allResorcesAreAvailable) {
          return new Booking()
     }

     // Try next time slot
     return GetBooking(..., ref numberOfTries);
}
```

As you can see I have a handle that ensures that the recursion never gets out of control (numberOfTries). However over time the algorithm is bound to try a lot of times and this results in Stackoverflow Exceptions. Any suggestion on how to avoid this? Increase the stack size (I do not like this)? Run the planning in threads? I am already considering rewriting the entire approach, but just wanted to see if anyone could give some advice.

Comment: Recursion is a beautiful and eloquent idea but I find if difficult to manage.  I would rewrite it because I'm a simple girl and I like simple, easy to maintain code.  The only thing I see wrong is the possibility that numberOfTries may not have an upward constraint.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that makes recursion useful. A simple loop could replace this.

Comment: This might just be a stylistic suggestion, since i dont know the range of inputs, but if you actually do need to do the recursion, instead of having numberOfTries-- at the beginning you could just approach your base case by changing return statement to:                                                               return GetBooking(..., ref numberOfTries-1) to avoid stack overflow if input is 0. But like the above comment says, from whats shown, theres no need for recursion.

Comment: This is very intesting! I just changed the code to use simple iteration instead, and the program actually finishes although it takes quite a while! Can someone please enlighten me as to why recursion is so much more demanding on resources? Is it because it builds X number of object per recursive call thereby stealing resource super fast?

Comment: @nath Recursive algorithms are at least O(n) in memory usage, because the environment has to keep a "stack" of the previous states of the recursion. There is a special case though: if the recursion is last statement of the function (before returning the value), then the algorithm can be changed to an iterative one. This usually implies keeping partial results as parameters of the recursive function.

Comment: @nath Although the function in your example is considered a "tail recursive" function, it is possible that C# does not offer tail-call recursion optimization, which means it is still a recursive and not an iterative function in the generated code

Comment: @nath Do you compile it for 64 bits or 32? And what version of .NET do you use? If I remember correctly, only 64 bit RyuJit compiler of 4.6 performs the tail recursion optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment @KABoissonneault! Switching from recursion to iteration solved my problem!

@galenus: It was compiled for 4.5.2 64 bit

Comment: anything done with recursion can be done with a `Stack` so i'd go for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved by moving away from recursion and instead write it as a simple loop/iteration. I solved it like this:

```
public Booking GetBooking(..., int numberOfTries) {
     while (true)
          numberOfTries--;
          if (numberOfTries == 0) {
               return null;
          }

          if (allResorcesAreAvailable) {
               return new Booking()
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Commonly written as a for loop: `for (int t = 0; t < numberOfTries; t++)` ... which is a lot easier to read and understand that it's finite.

Answer (score -1):

I Should note, from the code you post, it seems that you can do with simple looping design.

But i'll address the actual question "how to prevent recursion StackOverflow".

Anything done with recursion can be done with a simple `Stack`,
while with a `Stack`, you can have it on the heap and manage it with almost no limits...

lets take your code, would look something like this

```
public Booking GetBooking(..., int numberOfTries) 
{
 Stack<BookingStateData> stk = new Stack<BookingStateData>();

 while(!stk.isEmpty())
 {
  BookingStateData current = stk.Pop();

  if (current.allResorcesAreAvailable) {
    return new Booking(current...)
  }

  if(stk.Count > maxDepth) // if you want to limit the DFS Depth
     continue;

  stk.push(new BookingStateData(yada,yada)); // fake recursion.
 }
 return null;
}
```

Added Note: if you use a `Queue` instead of a `Stack`, you may use a BFS approach instead of the given DFS.